# Kendo TreeList with checkboxes

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-treeview

I'm using a Kendo UI TreeList control and need each parent node to be a checkbox. I have searched on how to use checkboxes in the TreeList but haven't found any examples yet. Does anyone know how to do this or if it is even possible?

Answer (score 2):

i worked in treelist kendo UI and i have bind the parent id and also create another column name as "manualparentid" which is also parentid..might be i'm doing wrong but the you can put condition on template

```
//Created Separate Class
public class TreePermission
{
   public int menuid { get; set; }
   public int parentmenuid { get; set; }
   public string menuname { get; set; }
   public bool isadd { get; set; } 
   public int manualparentid { get; set; }
}


 Html.Kendo().TreeList<TSBBAL.BAL.TreePermission>()
.Name("GridRolePermissions")
.Columns(colums =>
{
    colums.Add().Field(e => e.menuname).Width(150).Title("Menu Name");
    colums.Add().Field(e => e.isadd).Width(100).Title("Add").TemplateId("addtemplate"); 
}).DataSource(data => data.AutoSync(false)
    .ServerOperation(true)
    .Model(m =>
    {
        m.Id(f => f.menuid);
        m.ParentId(f => f.parentmenuid);
        m.Field(f => f.menuname);
        m.Field(f => f.isadd);  
        m.Expanded(true);
    }).Read(read => read.Action("MenuList", "User"))
)
```

- created template addtemplate

  ```
   <script id="addtemplate" type="text/x-kendo-template">  
  <div class="col-md-6">       

  # if(manualparentid !=0) {# 
      <input type="checkbox" onclick="CheckThePermission(#=menuid #,#=manualparentid #,'add')" id="chkadd_#=menuid #" mid="#=menuid #"  pid="add_#=manualparentid #"   name="chkadd" #= isadd ? checked='checked' : '' # /> 
  #} else {#   
      <input type="checkbox" onclick="CheckChildPermission(#=menuid #,'add')" id="chkadd_#=menuid #" mid="#=menuid #"  pid="add_#=manualparentid #"   name="chkadd" #= isadd ? checked='checked' : '' # /> 

  #}#
  </div>
  ```

  ```
   <script>
           function CheckThePermission(id,pid,obj) {
      //you will get the parent id 
      }
  </script>
  ```

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

You can replaces arrow *(sprite background)* with checkbox using CSS.

```
.k-i-expand, .k-plus, .k-plus-disabled {
   background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/zQtSf.png) top left !important;
}

.k-i-collapse, .k-minus, .k-minus-disabled {
   background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/5tDmY.png) top left !important;
}
```

[image][image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Checkboxes on only the parents is easily done through templating. Here is an example template:

```
<script id="treelist-checkbox-template" type="text/x-kendo-template">
    # if ( hasChildren ) { #
        <input type='checkbox' name='checkedFiles[#= id #]' value='true' />
    # } #
</script>
```

Then use the template like this:

```
$("#treelist").kendoTreeList({
    dataSource: dataSource,
    height: 540,
    columns: [
        { template: kendo.template($("#treelist-checkbox-template").html()), width: 32 },
        { field: "Position", expandable: true },
        { field: "Name" },
        { field: "Phone" }
    ],
    // Other options here
});
```

Here is a working Dojo example of this: http://dojo.telerik.com/@mrtaunus/eXiVO

Answer (score 0):

i'm using KendoTreeList Check boxes for Policies management kindly see my example i hope to be useful

Policy Model

```
  public class PolicyModel
{
    public PolicyModel(){}
    public string PolicyId { get; set; }
    public string PolicyName { get; set; }
    public string ParentID{ get; set; }
 }
```

PolicyTreeListModel

```
 public class PolicyTreeListModel
{
    public PolicyTreeListModel(){}
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string text { get; set; }
    public List<PolicyTreeListModel> items { get; set; }
    public bool expanded { get; set; }
 }
```

Policy webAPI Controller

```
    public class PoliciesController : ApiController
    {
        public IEnumerable<PolicyTreeListModel> GetPoliciesTree()
        {
            List<PolicyTreeListModel> ToReturen = new List<PolicyTreeListModel>();

            List<PolicyModel> DataFromDB = new List<PolicyModel>();
            using (var db = DBManager.CreateNewContext())
            {
                var data = db.Policies.ToList();
                foreach (var item in data)
                {
                    DataFromDB.Add(new PolicyModel() { PolicyId = item.PolicyId, PID = item.PID });
                }
            }
            foreach (var item in DataFromDB.Where(e => e.PID == null))
            {
                toreturen.Add(new PolicyTreeListModel()
                {
                    id = item.PolicyId,
                    text = item.PolicyName,
                    expanded = true,
                    items = GetSubItems(DataFromDB.ToList(), new List<PolicyTreeListModel>(), item.PolicyId)
                });
            }

            return ToReturen.OrderByDescending(e => e.text).ToList();
        }

     public List<PolicyTreeListModel> GetSubItems(List<PolicyModel> OrginalData,List<PolicyTreeListModel> SubItems,string PID)
        {
                foreach (var item in OrginalData.Where(e=>e.PID==PID))
                {
                    if (!SubItems.Any(e => e.id == item.PolicyId))
                        SubItems.Add(new PolicyTreeListModel() { id = item.PolicyId, text = item.PolicyName, expanded = true, items = GetItems(OrginalData, new List<Models.PolicyTreeListModel>(),item.PolicyId)});
                }
                return SubItems;
        }
    }
```

HTML Code

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/kendo.common.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/kendo.default.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/kendo.default.mobile.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/bootstrap.min.css" />
        <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div class="form-group" style="width:100%">
                <div class="form-inline" style="background-color: #428bca;">
                    <input class="k-textbox" placeholder="Search..." style="font-size:smaller;width:230px;margin-left:2px" id="searchTree" />
                    <label style="font-size:smaller;padding:2px;margin:2px;color:white"><input class="checkbox" style="font-size:smaller;padding:2px;margin:2px" id="chbAll" type="checkbox" value="" /><b>Select All</b></label>
                    <label style="font-size:smaller;padding:2px;margin:2px;color:white"><input class="checkbox" style="font-size:smaller;padding:2px;margin:2px" id="expandAll" type="checkbox" value="" /><b>Expand All</b></label>
                    <button class="btn btn-success" id="savePolicies" style="padding:5px;margin:2px;width:100px;font-family:sans-serif"><i class="fa fa-floppy-o" style="font-size:medium"> Save</i></button>
                    <button class="btn btn-default" id="clearPolicoies" style="padding:5px;margin:2px;width:100px;font-family:sans-serif"><i class="fa fa-eraser" style="font-size:medium;"> Clear</i></button>
                </div>
                <div id="policiestree" style="height:520px;width:100%;background-color: gainsboro;font-size:small;text-align:left;font-weight:bold"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
 <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
     $("#policiestree").kendoTreeView({
                checkboxes: { checkChildren: true },
                dataSource: [],
            });
            $("#searchTree").on("input", function () {
                var query = this.value.toLowerCase();
                var dataSource = $("#policiestree").data("kendoTreeView").dataSource;
                filter(dataSource, query);
            });
            $("#chbAll").click(function () {
                chbAllOnChange();
            });
            $("#expandAll").attr("checked", true);
            $("#expandAll").click(function () {
                var treeView = $("#policiestree").data("kendoTreeView");
                if (this.checked) { treeView.expand(".k-item"); }
                else { treeView.collapse(".k-item"); }
            });
            function filter(dataSource, query) {
                var hasVisibleChildren = false;
                var data = dataSource instanceof kendo.data.HierarchicalDataSource && dataSource.data();
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    var item = data[i];
                    var text = item.text.toLowerCase();
                    var itemVisible =
                        query === true // parent already matches
                        || query === "" // query is empty
                        || text.indexOf(query) >= 0; // item text matches query
                    var anyVisibleChildren = filter(item.children, itemVisible || query); // pass true if parent matches
                    hasVisibleChildren = hasVisibleChildren || anyVisibleChildren || itemVisible;
                    item.hidden = !itemVisible && !anyVisibleChildren;
                }
                if (data) {
                    // re-apply filter on children
                    dataSource.filter({ field: "hidden", operator: "neq", value: true });
                }
                return hasVisibleChildren;
            }
            function checkUncheckAllNodes(nodes, checked) {
                for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
                    nodes[i].set("checked", checked);

                    if (nodes[i].hasChildren) {
                        checkUncheckAllNodes(nodes[i].children.view(), checked);
                    }
                }
            }
            function chbAllOnChange() {
                var checkedNodes = [];
                var treeView = $("#policiestree").data("kendoTreeView");
                var isAllChecked = $('#chbAll').prop("checked");
                checkUncheckAllNodes(treeView.dataSource.view(), isAllChecked)
            }
            function GetPoliciesTree() {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "/api/Policies/GetPoliciesTree",
                    success: function (result) {
                        $("#policiestree").data("kendoTreeView").dataSource.data(result);
                    }
                });
            }
});
 </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```